# Error importing into my database: ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 217004: Table 'caol2.cao_curriculo' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, import, xampp, create-table

I'm facing a weird issue while trying to import into my database.

- The "root" user has all privileges
- The database name is the same in phpmyadmin and in the .sql file (caol2)

The failing line is the following (217004):

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `caol2`.`cao_consulta_curriculo_por_vaga` AS (select `caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_curriculo` AS `co_curriculo`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`ds_nome_profissional` AS `ds_nome_profissional`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`dt_nascimento` AS `dt_nascimento`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`nu_pretencao_salarial` AS `nu_pretencao_salarial`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`nu_dias_disponibilidade` AS `nu_dias_disponibilidade`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_estado` AS `co_estado`,`caol2`.`cao_uf`.`ds_uf` AS `ds_estado`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_cidade` AS `co_cidade`,`caol2`.`cao_cidade`.`no_cidade` AS `ds_cidade`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`conclusao_graduacao` AS `conclusao_graduacao`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_vaga_desejada` AS `co_vaga`,'1' AS `principal`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`dt_alteracao` AS `dt_alteracao`,`caol2`.`cao_vaga`.`co_escritorio` AS `co_escritorio`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`ds_email_contato` AS `ds_email_contato`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`status` AS `status` from (((`caol2`.`cao_curriculo` join `caol2`.`cao_vaga` on((`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_vaga_desejada` = `caol2`.`cao_vaga`.`co_vaga`))) join `caol2`.`cao_uf` on((`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_estado` = `caol2`.`cao_uf`.`co_uf`))) join `caol2`.`cao_cidade` on((`caol2`.`cao_cidade`.`co_cidade` = `caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_cidade`)))) union (select `caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_curriculo` AS `co_curriculo`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`ds_nome_profissional` AS `ds_nome_profissional`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`dt_nascimento` AS `dt_nascimento`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`nu_pretencao_salarial` AS `nu_pretencao_salarial`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`nu_dias_disponibilidade` AS `nu_dias_disponibilidade`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_estado` AS `co_estado`,`caol2`.`cao_uf`.`ds_uf` AS `ds_estado`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_cidade` AS `co_cidade`,`caol2`.`cao_cidade`.`no_cidade` AS `ds_cidade`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`conclusao_graduacao` AS `conclusao_graduacao`,`caol2`.`cao_vaga`.`co_vaga` AS `co_vaga`,'2' AS `principal`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`dt_alteracao` AS `dt_alteracao`,`caol2`.`cao_vaga`.`co_escritorio` AS `co_escritorio`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`ds_email_contato` AS `ds_email_contato`,`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`status` AS `status` from ((((`caol2`.`cao_curriculo` join `caol2`.`cao_curriculo_vaga` on(((`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_curriculo` = `caol2`.`cao_curriculo_vaga`.`co_curriculo`) and (`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_vaga_desejada` <> `caol2`.`cao_curriculo_vaga`.`co_vaga`)))) join `caol2`.`cao_vaga` on((`caol2`.`cao_vaga`.`co_vaga` = `caol2`.`cao_curriculo_vaga`.`co_vaga`))) join `caol2`.`cao_uf` on((`caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_estado` = `caol2`.`cao_uf`.`co_uf`))) join `caol2`.`cao_cidade` on((`caol2`.`cao_cidade`.`co_cidade` = `caol2`.`cao_curriculo`.`co_cidade`))));
```

The "cao_curriculo" table is created at line 220234:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cao_curriculo` (
  `co_curriculo` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `linkedin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_nome_profissional` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dt_nascimento` date NOT NULL,
  `nu_pretencao_salarial` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nu_dias_disponibilidade` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_graduacao` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conclusao_graduacao` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_pos_graduacao` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conclusao_pos` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co_estado` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co_cidade` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_impressao_entrevista_pessoal` text,
  `ds_email_contato` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dt_alteracao` date NOT NULL,
  `ds_bairro` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co_vaga_desejada` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ds_foto` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `sexo` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exp_empresas` text,
  `telefone` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avaliacao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'APROVADO, REPROVADO, CONTRATADO',
  `aceita_freelance` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disp_freelance` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`co_curriculo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2449 ;
```

The final result is just 32 of 158 tables imported.

I tried to import from phpmyadmin, and XAMPP mysql console, with same result.

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is strange slightly that database is specfied for each table/field name in CREATE VIEW, but is not specified in CREATE TABLE...

Comment: *The "cao_curriculo" table is created at line 220234* Does it really exists after script finishing (even errorneously)? Does the problematic line is executed successfully in this moment?

Comment: After the line 217004 comes this:
```
INSERT INTO `cao_consulta_curriculo_por_vaga` (`co_curriculo`, `ds_nome_profissi..........
```
And I see the table "cao_consulta_curriculo_por_vaga" is successfully created with its rows. After that, the table "cao_co_experiencia" is created with its rows.
But after that, comes the creation of "cao_curriculo". That table is not created and the import stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by:

- Exporting the database using MySQL workbench
- Importing the .sql file using XAMPP MySQl shell